# SQL query to select a value based on certain criteria

Tags: mysql

I have the following data in my Database:

```
Id      MachineName CategoryName    CounterName  InstanceName   RawValue
11180   SERVER64    Process         ID Process   w3wp#2         2068
11180   SERVER64    Process         Working Set  w3wp#2         9310208
```

Now I want to achieve that if I find the value '2068' for the "ID Process" Countername then I want to retrieve the Working Set RawValue. So based on the value of ID Process I now the **[InstanceName]** = w3wp#2 and therefore I want the value to retrieve = 9310208

Now I tried different SQL queries:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [dbo].[LoadTest]
  WHERE [LoadTestRunId] = '11180' and [CategoryName] = 'Process' and [InstanceName] like 'w3wp%'
```

But I need a filter. Can anyone guide me into the right direction?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server? Remove the irrelevant tag.

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server`? This looks like SQL Server, due to the use of the `dbo` schema

Comment: this is cleary SQL-server syntax because off the use of the brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here will help you. I used variable because you need to find a specific ID

**SQL Code**

```
declare @myt table (id int,MachineName nvarchar(50),CategoryName nvarchar(50),CounterName nvarchar(50),InstanceName nvarchar(50),RawValue int)

insert into @myt
values

(11180 ,'SERVER64','Process','ID Process','w3wp#2',2068),
(11180 ,'SERVER64','Process','Working Set','w3wp#2',9310208)

declare @FindID int

Set @FindID = 2068;

with IdProcess as (
Select * from  @myt 
where RawValue = @FindID and CounterName = 'ID Process'
)
Select a.ID,a.MachineName,a.CategoryName,b.CounterName,a.InstanceName,b.RawValue from IdProcess a
inner join @myt b on a.InstanceName = b.InstanceName and b.CounterName='Working Set'
```

**SQL Code without variable based on ID and InstanceName**

```
with IdProcess as (
Select * from  @myt 
where  CounterName = 'ID Process'
)
Select a.ID,a.MachineName,a.CategoryName,b.CounterName,a.InstanceName,b.RawValue from IdProcess a
inner join @myt b on a.id = b.id and a.InstanceName = b.InstanceName and b.CounterName='Working Set'
```

**SQL Code with CategoryName filter**

```
with IdProcess as (
Select * from  @myt 
where  CounterName = 'ID Process' and CategoryName = 'Process'
)
Select a.ID,a.MachineName,a.CategoryName,b.CounterName,a.InstanceName,b.RawValue from IdProcess a
inner join @myt b on a.id = b.id and a.InstanceName = b.InstanceName and b.CounterName='Working Set'
where b.CategoryName = 'Process'
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: thank you! It is a bit difficult for me to understand. Would you perhaps also paste it in terms like: `WHERE [LoadTestRunId] = '11180' and [CategoryName] = 'Process'` etc.?

Comment: No need to use where on LoadTestRunID since you use it in the join. But you can just write Where CategoryName = 'Process' on both sets if you want. I dont know the reason for this filter since its the same, but i assume you can have other values than process?

Comment: Yes! Exactly. This is just a small piece out of the database.

Comment: I updated the answer. I dont think you need the filter on your ID, since its filtered in the join, so it only hits the values where it matches on ID.

Answer (score 0):

This will execute.

```
Select * from (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LoadTestRunId ORDER BY LoadTestRunId DESC) as row,*
FROM [dbo].[LoadTest]) t1 where row=1
```

with your where clause

```
Select * from (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LoadTestRunId ORDER BY LoadTestRunId DESC),*
FROM [dbo].[LoadTest]) t1 where t1=1
and [LoadTestRunId] = '11180' and [CategoryName] = 'Process' and [InstanceName] like 'w3wp%'
```